# Multiple select statements in a stored procedure for use in classic ASP

Tags: stored-procedures, asp-classic

Currently I have a classic asp application, and one of the page has logic like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Condition
//DO stuff
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Condition
//DO stuff
SELECT * FROM Table3 WHERE Condition
//Execute
```

I need to convert this into a stored procedure.  Now I know how to use stored procedures in ASP generally, but I don't know how to do it with multiple selects.  How can I generate three sets of data and use them properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using ADO or ADO.Net ?  Both have the capability to return multiple recordsets from a stored procedure.  In Ado, if a stored procedure has multiple Selects in it, you can access the second, and subsequent Resultsets (ADO `RecordSets`) in your client code by calling `Recordset.NextRecordSet`.

In ADO.Net, When a Stored proc has multiple Selects, ADO.Net will put the results of each Select into a `DataTable` object, and put each `DataTable` into the `Tables` collection of the `DataSet` object which returned by the ADO.Net `command.Execute()` method.